# Least Squares Re Synthesis of Short Time Fourier Transform (STFT)

Tags: matlab, algorithms, stft, time-frequency, least-squares

Working with my own MATLAB implementation of the short-time Fourier transform (STFT), I've managed to write code for the analysis step where a 1D time-domain signal $s[t]$ is progressively windowed, taken into the Fourier domain and arranged in a 2D matrix $S[t,\omega]$.  Each element in the 2D matrix is a function of time $t$ and frequency $\omega$.

This [presentation](http://recherche.ircam.fr/anasyn/roebel/amt_audiosignale/VL2.pdf) is a rather nice overview of the STFT, and gives a number of equations detailing the analysis and re-synthesis steps.

However, I would like to be able to arbitrarily modify $S[t,\omega]$, and then use the re-synthesis to get back $s[t]$.

I believe that I should be able to change $S[t,\omega]$ in whatever way that I want, and then obtain $s[t]$ by the re-synthesis procedure.  This seems to be very similar to the idea of the [phase vocoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_vocoder).

As noted in section 3.1 of the presentation, the time-domain signal $s[t]$ can be recomposed using a least-squares procedure.  This is given as Equation (6) in the 1984 paper by [Griffin and Lim](http://musicweb.ucsd.edu/~sdubnov/catbox/Reader/GriffinLimMSTFT.pdf).

The least-squares procedure is required to be applied when $S[t,\omega]$ is modified in some way.

**Question**:

- What does Equation (6) of the Griffin and Lim paper mean?
- What steps do I follow to numerically implement Equation (6)?

In the presentation, the equation is written in a slightly different way:

$$x(n)=\frac{\sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty w\left(n-lI\right)y\left(lI, n\right)}{\sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty w\left(n-lI\right)^2}$$

Note that $x(n)$ is the re-synthesized time-domain sequence, $w(n)$ is the window function, and $y(n)$ is the time-domain version of a column of the 2D matrix.

**Steps:**

From the presentation, here are the steps that I think are required to do the re-synthesis:

1. Let `w_n` be the discrete window vector and `y_n(:,k)` be the time domain vector computed using the IFFT on a column `k` of the 2D matrix.  Both `w_n` and `y_n(:,k)` are the same length.
2. Then, using Matlab syntax, we compute the point-by-point multiplication:
   `w_n .* y_n(:,k)`

- Is this the numerator of the expression above?
- What happens during steps 3 and 4?
- What do the infinite summations signify?

Comment: Yes, `w_n .* y_n(:,k)` looks like the numerator, except that perhaps you'll need to make `y_n` the same length as `w_n`:  `y_n(n:n+M,:)` where `M` is the window length.

Comment: @PeterK: Thanks, Peter.  So if `y_n` has a greater length than the window size due to the original time-domain signal being zero-padded, how do I cut `w_n .* y_n(:,k)`?  Why would I want to take the very beginning of the signal `y_n(n:n+M,:)`, and how do I overlap-add the frames to reconstruct the signal?  How do I deal with the denominator?

Comment: Generally, `y_n` will have a much longer length than the window size --- zero padded or not.  Therefore, you need to choose *some* part of `y_n` that is the same size as `w_n`. I probably got the indices wrong: if you choose the front `M` samples it'll be more like `y_n(n-M+1:n,k)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least-squares re-synthesis procedure is very similar to the overlap-add (OLA) procedure.

Let `w_n` be the discrete window vector and `y_n(:,k)` be the time domain vector computed using the IFFT on a column `k` of the 2D matrix. Both `w_n` and `y_n(:,k)` are the same length.

Then, using Matlab syntax, we compute the point-by-point multiplication with the window:

`w_n .* y_n(:,k)`

As mentioned in the comments above, the `y_n` is trimmed to be the same length as the window `w_t`.  The `w_n .* y_n(:,k)` is then overlap-added in the same fashion as shown in the code associated with my previous post on the inverse STFT [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/inverse-short-time-fourier-transform-algorithm-described-in-words).  The overlap-added sequence is the `numerator` of the expression shown in the original question above.

The same overlap-add operation is applied to the squared window `w_t.^2`.  This is the `denominator` of the expression shown in the original question above.

Then, the final re-synthesized output is simply the point-by-point division of the numerator by the denominator.  In Matlab syntax,

`numerator ./ denominator`