# A DFT-based phasor estimation

Tags: dft, digital-filters, c#

I have the sample set of ideal and real secondary current during CT saturation, need to apply the DFT analysis to samples and estimate the fundamental phasor (magnitude and phase angle) of samples:

[image]

I am far from digital signal processing but I suppose the main idea is to perform computation at each sample $m$ on the basis of $N$ historical samples.
I've been trying to apply the following expressions:
$$I_{k}(m)=\sqrt{I_{RE}^2(m)+I_{IM}^2(m)}$$
$$\varphi(m)=\arctan\lgroup\frac{I_{IM}(m)}{I_{RE}(m)}\rgroup$$
$$I_{RE}(m)=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}i(m-n)\cdot \cos\lgroup\frac{2\pi k n}{N}\rgroup$$
$$I_{IM}(m)=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}i(m-n)\cdot \sin\lgroup\frac{2\pi k n}{N}\rgroup$$
where:
$m$ is the current sample
$n$ is the sample number in a cycle (window)
$k$ is the harmonic number
$I_{k}(m)$ is the output sample for harmonic $k$
$i(m-n)$ is the input sample set (stored samples)
$N$ is the number of samples in cycle (window)

Here is my c# code:

```
private DFTsample[] FourierAnalysis(List<double> inputSamples, List<double> inputTime, int k)
    {
        DFTsample[] dFTsamples = new DFTsample[inputSamples.Count];

        for (int m = 0; m < inputSamples.Count; m++)
        {
            if (inputTime.ElementAt(m) < 0)
            {
                dFTsamples[m] = new DFTsample() { Abs = 0, Angle = 0, Re = 0, Im = 0 };
                continue;
            }

            if(inputTime.ElementAt(m) >= 0)
            {
                dFTsamples[m] = new DFTsample();
                double Re = 0;
                double Im = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
                {
                    Re += 2 / N * inputSamples[m - n] * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * k * n / N);
                    Im += 2 / N * inputSamples[m - n] * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * k * n / N);
                }
                dFTsamples[m].Re = Re;
                dFTsamples[m].Im = Im;
                dFTsamples[m].Abs = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Re, 2) + Math.Pow(Im, 2));
                dFTsamples[m].Angle = Math.Atan2(Re, Im) * 180 / Math.PI; 
            }
        }
        return dFTsamples;
    }
```

My result doesn't seem right, something went wrong:

[image: My result]

I'd really appreciate it if you'd let me know how to use the DFT and compute the magnitude and phase angle of the secondary current.

Comment: Your pictures appear to be behind a pay wall. At least I can't see them

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you for noticing. I've changed links, hope they'll work well

Comment: Don't you have the $\sin(\cdot)$ and $\cos(\cdot)$ swapped?
$$I_{RE}(m)=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}i(m-n)\cdot \cos\lgroup\frac{2\pi k n}{N}\rgroup$$
$$I_{IM}(m)=\frac{2}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}i(m-n)\cdot \sin\lgroup\frac{2\pi k n}{N}\rgroup$$

Comment: And you wanna changed $\arctan(\cdot)$ to $\arg\{\}$.  get all four quadrants.

Comment: If you do this right, and use sliding DFTs for each $X[k]$, you can minimize computations, assuming $N$ is a few K.  Now, if you do that, your sin and cos will stay synchronous with the harmonics as $m$ increases.  That will change the definition of $\varphi(m)$ into a more lowpass form.  Like an envelope.

Comment: [Here is exactly the math](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/is-windowed-fourier-transform-a-synonym-for-stft/45631#45631).  Let the hop $H=1$.  Also your window would be rectangular, not a Hann (unless you did something very tricky with TIIR filters).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You're totally right. I've updated the code according to your equations, but it still looks pretty terrible. I need to learn more about sliding DFT. I've just thought I can estimate the magnitude and phase angle using a relatively simple algorithm

Comment: The sliding DFT is a like the *moving sum* or *moving average*.  each new sample is added to the summation and the old sample that falls offa the edge is subtracted from the summation.